# Error in displaying the title

Tags: titles

I'm experiencing problems in visualizing the title of my paper. I'm currently using the bare_jrnl.tex template from IEEEtran.
The distribution is MiXTex with the Texmaker editor.

Here is the code of the initial part of the paper, where the document class, the packages and the title are specified.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
%packages
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  \usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\else
  \usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\fi

\begin{document}

\title{Enabling visually impaired people to learn three-dimensional tactile graphics}

\author{Luca~Brayda,Mariacarla~Memeo,%
\thanks{Robotics, Brain and Cognitive Sciences department\\ Genoa, Italy}}%

\markboth{Enabling visually impaired people}%
{}

\meaning\maketitle
```

The code is compiled without errors, but what I see in the pdf is the following:
[image: In the selected area should be displayed the title.]

Do you have any suggestions about this?
Thanks a lot.

Mariacarla

Comment: Remove the `\meaning` before `\maketitle`, so that `\meaning\maketitle` becomes only `\maketitle`. `\meaning\foo` prints the macro definition of `\foo` in the document body instead of executing it. This is what you are seeing here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! 

I inserted \meaning in order to avoid several error messages, but from your explanation I see why I could not see them anymore. 

Once I remove \meaning I have around 20 errors like this:

 ! Use of \@topnewpage doesn't match its definition.\new@ifnextchar ...served@d = #1\def \reserved@a {#2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f... \maketitle

They all present the \@topnewpage, but one which has the @icentertr.
Do you have any ideas of what could it be?
Thanks again.

Comment: Don't use `\\` to break lines in the title, use `\break` instead.

Comment: Blast, my last comment got mangled. That should have read *Don't use ``\\`` to break lines, use `\break` instead.*

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
It was exactly that, the \\ in both the title and the \thanks{} sections.

Answer (score 3):

The original problem was the `\meaning` before `\maketitle` which instead of executing `\maketitle` just printed its macro definition.

The

```
 ! Use of \@topnewpage doesn't match its definition
```

error can be circumvented by not breaking lines with `\\` in the title and thanks, bit with `\newline` instead. See also http://www.jacow.org/Authors/UsingLaTeX